# How to enable DEBUG mode in Docker for IBM Websphere Traditional Image by Default

Tags: docker, debugging, websphere, websphere-8

we have an application WAR that runs on traditional websphere. For local testing we create a docker image for our app based on the "ibmcom/websphere-traditional:8.5.5.22" docker image.

This works fine as such, but when I want to debug my app within the docker container via remote debugging I have to enable DEBUG mode for the server manually through the admin console first. And then I need to restart the server/container.

I am wondering is there a different way of doing this? Like applying some props to the new image that will start my application server in DEBUG mode by default?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've been playing with wsadmin scripts. When making the change through web adminconsole and scripting the change out as suggested by lwestby I came up with the following python func which I included in our install.py.

But its not doing the job. Where would I actually see the logger or stdout output from such python scripts?

Thanks

```
def enableDebug():
    try:
        server1 = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:DefaultCell01/Node:DefaultNode01/Server:server1/')
        AdminConfig.create('DebugService', server1, '[[BSFDebugPort "4444"] [enable "true"] [jvmDebugPort "7777"] [jvmDebugArgs "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777"] [debugClassFilters ""] [BSFLoggingLevel "0"]]')
        jvm = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine', server1)
        AdminConfig.modify(jvm[0], '[[debugMode "true"]]')
    except:
        logger("EXCEPTION ENABLING DEBUG FOR server1")
```

Comment: If you look at the documentation: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional#adding-properties-during-build-phase  you'll see it steers you towards 1) externalizing your config into a config properties file following these instructions: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=configuration-extracting-properties-files-using-wsadmin-scripting   and then 2) COPYing that properties file into a special location in the Dockerfile, where the WebSphere Docker tooling/helpers will "apply" it.   So you could do this for DEBUG with JVM config.

Comment: Realize that would be more helpful with an example line or two, but will post the comment until someone else does a better answer.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was thinking along those lines. But I like lwestby's answer too. Sounds easier for now.

Comment: As far as your enableDebug() script... you did end with an AdminConfig.save(), right? (Not including one is an easy mistake to make).

Comment: I would usually debug a script by launching `wsadmin.sh -lang jython` and then running the script by `execfile("/path/to/myDebug.py")`

Comment: Thanks again, yes 'save' is being called in the 'main' func after enableDebug()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution extracting properties-file based configuration from admin console updates

1. Start initial container

`docker run --name mywas -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 ibmcom/websphere-traditional:8.5.5.22`

2. Grab generated wsadmin password

`docker exec -it mywas  bash -c "cat /tmp/PASSWORD";`

3. Open admin console (point browser to:  https://localhost:9043/ibm/console/ )
4. Click to enable server for debug (use [Debugging Service](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=applications-debugging-service-details) or **Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine**
5. Click **Apply** to save
6. Launch wsadmin

`docker exec -it mywas bash -c "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -user wsadmin -password <password>"`
(Accept self-signed cert. if prompted)

7. (Within wsadmin session), extract properties

`print AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('-configData Node=DefaultNode01 -propertiesFileName /home/was/jvm.props -filterMechanism SELECTED_SUBTYPES -selectedSubTypes JavaVirtualMachine')`

8. Back in host, copy properties out of container

`docker cp mywas:/home/was/jvm.props jvm.props`

9. Copy **jvm.props** properties file to location of your Dockerfile and add COPY to /work/config

```
FROM ibmcom/websphere-traditional:8.5.5.22
COPY --chown=was:root jvm.props /work/config/
RUN /work/configure.sh
```

10. `docker build` (notice the build will take a bit of time, as your props are "applied" via wsadmin via the websphere docker tooling utils)

Your new image will be enabled for debug.

### COMMENTS

This is clearly more work than adding a single wsadmin script (as in @lwestby's answer).  One nice aspect of the properties file approach is you only have to learn a single wsadmin command AdminTask.extractConfigProperties, instead of learning different commands for each admin/config object type.  Learning the different commands isn't as much of a challenge as it might seem given the assistance mentioned in lwestby's answer but there might be times when it's easier to just work with the [properties](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=wsadmin-using-properties-files-manage-system-configuration) more directly, possibly filtering them, like in the example in this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Scott. This works perfectly and agree that it seems clearer and more elegant. Your awesome step by step instructions might have helped with that, too! ;) Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that you'll need to configure a new image from your base image that starts in debug mode. Since it sounds like you've already tried toggling it in the admin console, you can actually get the wsadmin command to change the JVM settings by doing exactly what you did, and looking for the Command Assistance header in the right column:

[image: Command Assistance in the Admin Console]

As soon as you check the box to enable Debug mode and click OK, click that "View administrative scripting command for last action" link to get the command, something like:

```
AdminTask.setJVMProperties('[-nodeName DefaultNode01 -serverName server1 -verboseModeClass false -verboseModeGarbageCollection true -verboseModeJNI false -runHProf false -hprofArguments -debugMode true -debugArgs "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777" -executableJarFileName -genericJvmArguments "-Xnoloa" -disableJIT false]')
```

(Don't just copy paste what I have here in case your image has other settings changed.)

Then you can add this link to an existing or new wsadmin `.py` file that you apply as part of the [image build process](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional#adding-an-application-and-advanced-configuration-during-build-phase). Make sure the file runs `AdminConfig.save()` after the command.

Then build a new image and that image should start up in debug mode by default.

Comment: Thanks, I followed that trail but no joy for now. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Hmm, how did it fail? You might need to expose the debug port externally to connect to it...

Comment: Thanks yes I included the debug port both in my Dockerfile and in my maven-docker plugin config in pom.xml. I was able to successfully connect the debugger.
Just trying to automate the debug=on config now.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and help. I'm new to this and didnt understand how to run/test the python. In the end I got there with Scott's instructions quicker but I really appreciate the help. Thanks again.